# Can the click event be combined with mouseout?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the best way of combining the click() with mouseout(). Basically, i want a list item to show if a certain link is clicked, and once the mouse goes out of the parent div of the link, i want the list to disapper.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content_inner').hide();
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $('.content_inner').fadeIn();
    });//mouseout

});
<div class=".container">
    <a href="#" class="clickme">Click me!</a>
    <ul class="content_inner">
        <li><a href="#">testing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">testing</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is attach an "onMouseLeave" event listener to the container div so that when the mouse moves away it will check if that div `.content_inner` has been shown and if so, hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content_inner').hide();
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $('.content_inner').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.container').mouseleave(function() {
        if ($('.content_inner').is(':visible')) {
            $('.content_inner').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please give a quick explanation of this code? I understand it fine, but others might not. +1 for using : visible - i would have used a class.

Comment: Yeah good point. I hope my explanation will suffice. If not, feel free to edit it hehe.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.clickme').bind('click mouseout',function() {
    $('.content_inner').fadeIn();
});
```

And there you go ^_^

Although you might want to fix this line from `<div class=".container">` to `<div class="container">`